# Layered Navigation on custom product collection in magento

Tags: magento

Layered navigation is not showing on my custom listings. `New products` or `All Products` listing does not allow layered navigation, even though I tried changing `layout.xml`

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" as="mynav2" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>    
</reference>
```

It is not working with the below code as well

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
```

Please guide on how to show layered navigation for my custom product listing.

Comment: Could you pls post your product collection code ?

Comment: $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
       ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
       ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
       ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price',array('neq'=>''))
       ->addMinimalPrice()
                      ->addFinalPrice()
                      ->addTaxPercents()
       ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count())
                ->setOrder($this->get_order(), $this->get_order_dir())
                ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());

Comment: can you please check the code or give me code for new products collection